# vb.net Error after Adding typed text item from datagridViewComboboxColumn into database

Tags: vb.net, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Basically, I wan't the user to be able to type into datagridViewComboboxColumn
and if there is no match it will automatically save the text into the database, update the BindingSource and select the item.

Heres what I have so far.
The bindingsource:

```
With acctTitleCombo6
    .AutoComplete = True
    Try
        .DataSource = ds4
        .DisplayMember = "desc_description"
        .ValueMember = "desc_id"
        .DataPropertyName = "desc_id"
        .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End With
```

Changing combobox style to dropdown in EditingControlShowing:

```
Dim comboBoxColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = DataGridView2.Columns(0)
If (DataGridView2.CurrentCellAddress.X = comboBoxColumn.DisplayIndex) Then
    Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
    If (cb IsNot Nothing) Then
        cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
    End If
End If
```

Checking if typed text is already in the source item (CellValidating event).

```
Dim comboBoxColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = DataGridView2.Columns(0)
cs2.Open()
Dim comm, comm2, comm3 As New MySqlCommand
comm.Connection = cs2
Dim msgAddDesc As String = "Your description is currently not in the list." & vbNewLine & _
    "Would you like to add '"

If (e.ColumnIndex = comboBoxColumn.DisplayIndex) And Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.FormattedValue) Then
    Dim itemIE As IEnumerator = comboBoxColumn.Items.GetEnumerator
    itemIE.Reset()
    Dim thisItem As DataRowView
    Dim exist As Boolean = False
    While itemIE.MoveNext()
        thisItem = CType(itemIE.Current(), DataRowView)
        Dim valueMember As Object = thisItem.Row.ItemArray(0)
        Dim displayMember As Object = thisItem.Row.ItemArray(1)
        If displayMember.ToString = e.FormattedValue Then
            exist = True
        End If
    End While

    If exist = False Then
        If MessageBox.Show(msgAddDesc & e.FormattedValue & "' to the list?", "Does not exist", _
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
           comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ref_description(desc_description) " & _
               "VALUES(@description)"
            With comm.Parameters
                .Add("@description", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = e.FormattedValue
            End With
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            comm.Parameters.Clear()
        End If
    End If
End If
cs2.Close()
```

Now, whenever I add a new item into the database, this error comes up but sometimes it doesn't:

```
The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
System.FormatException: Value '' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.

at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell.ParseFormattedValue(Object formattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PushFormattedValue(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCurrentCell, Object formattedValue, Exception& exception)
```

Another question is, how can I update the combobox after I add the new item into the database, then I also want to automatically select the new item when the user press enter or tab (only when there's a new item added into the database).

Comment: change `e.FormattedValue`  to `e.FormattedValue.ToString ` (`.Add("@description", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = e.FormattedValue.ToString `)and try

Comment: I have tried your suggestion wingedpanther but the error still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I can help. However, the error comes from DataGridView, not combo. I suspect, that you update the datagridview at the same time (as you try to update the combo), which will not work. I think you need to finish cell editing first (incl. validation), then you can update the datagridview. I'd try to move it to CellEndEdit() event.

Answer (score 0):

*how can I update the combobox*: I don't see the code, how you load the ComboBox in the first place.

Usually, you just update related dataset and re-assign it to ComboBox.DataSource, or you can use databinding (no need to update then, but one usually uses it if in need of more binding features).

```
Private Sub LoadUpdateSubListCombo()
        Dim cmdText as String
        cmdText = "SELECT ID,SubName FROM SubmarinesTable "
        Dim ds as DataSet
        ds = MyDataAccessLayer.GetQueryResults(cmdText)
        Dim SubDT As DataTable = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
        cb3.DataSource = SubDT
        cb3.ValueMember = "ID"
        cb3.DisplayMember = "SubName"
End Sub
```

...where cb3 is a ComboBox...

Comment: sorry for my incomplete code, but the first block of code in my post is where I load the combobox. If you can see clearly, there's a line `.DataSource = ds4` its where the data is and that block of code is just a part of a function I call in the form load.
I ask where I update the combobox source because every time I do it in the `CellValidating` event there's a run time error.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that combo setting. I'm not sure, if I can help. However, the error comes from DataGridView, not combo. I suspect, that you update the datagridview at the same time (as you try to update the combo), which will not work. I _think_ you need to finish cell editing first (incl. validation), then you can update the datagridview. I'd try to move it to CellEndEdit() event.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to update and select the new item in the combobox using `CellEndEdit()` event. And apparently I only needed to enclose that block of code where I insert data into database in a `Try-Catch`. I don't know why that solved the problem but it worked. lol
Now if you can make your comment as a post so I can accept it as an answer. TY